# How to stop an application from outputing sound?

Tags: gnome, sound, pulseaudio, output

I have an application which makes a lot of noise, and there seems to be no way of turning off the noise it makes (it plays some music while running etc), so I was wondering if I can just make it so that that application when run is not allowed to output sound?

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once an application is already running if you launch the `gnome-control-center`, then go to the `Sound` section:

[image: gnome-control-center Sound button]

After you have entered that section go to the `Applications` tab:

[image: Sound Applications tab indication]

And then you will be able to change the volume for individual applications (only applications currently outputting sound will be listed):

[image: Applications tab]

You can use the `On/Off` sliders to mute and unmute the volume.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the application with `pasuspender`. Open a terminal and run `pasuspender app_executable`. For example, with VLC:

`pasuspender vlc`

This will suspend pulseaudio while the application runs.

Comment: And it won't do the same for any other application? So for instance if I did this for Firefox, would VLC still be able to play music that I would be able to hear?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda I tested this out of interest, with a few applications, it did work but completely broke video playback in firefox and smplayer and audio playback in amarok, closing the program opened by the command fixed playback instantly. So no it won't mute your application and allow music playback, perhaps Eduardo knows a fix?

Comment: The whole point of me doing this is because I want to stop the continues non-stop sound from a certain application while I play music in the background from another application.

Comment: So it's no use if it breaks some of the other stuff.